# Persisting a Joint Table in JPA

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have three entities, Trader, Portfolio and Member. Each Trader has a Portfolio and a Portfolio can have many Members. I have set up the following relationships. I'm not sure how to use the Jointable that is created, i.e. Portfolio_PORTFOLIOID and members_MEMBERID. Obviously I'd like to associate each portfolid with member id's, however I'm not sure how to go about this. How is the jointable data persisted?

My `Portfolio` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Portfolio")
@NamedQuery(
name="findPortfolioByTrader",
query="SELECT p FROM Portfolio p" +
" WHERE Trader = :trader"
)
public class Portfolio {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer portfolioId;
@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastUpdate;
private Integer balance;
private Trader trader;
private Collection<Member> members;

public Portfolio() {

    this.lastUpdate = new Date();
}
public Portfolio(Integer balance, Trader trader) {

    this.lastUpdate =  new Date();
    this.balance = balance;
    this.trader = trader;
}

public Integer getPortfolioId() {
    return portfolioId;
}

public void setPortfolioId(Integer portfolioId) {
    this.portfolioId = portfolioId;
}

public Date getLastUpdate() {
    return lastUpdate;
}

public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="MEMBER_PORTFOLIO",
        joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="Member_MEMBERID", referencedColumnName="MEMBERID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="portfolio_PORTFOLIOID", referencedColumnName="PORTFOLIOID")
)
public Collection<Member> getMembers() {
    return members;
}

public void setMembers(Collection<Member> members) {
    this.members = members;
}

@OneToOne(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="portfolio")
public Trader getTrader() 
{
    return trader;
}

public void setTrader(Trader trader)
{
    this.trader = trader;
}

public Integer getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(Integer balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}


}
```

My `Member` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Member")
@NamedQuery(
name="findAllMembers",
query="SELECT m FROM Member m " +  
"ORDER BY m.memberId"
)
public class Member implements java.io.Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -468520665316481235L;

private String memberId;
private String forename;
private String surname;
private Integer position;
private Integer majority;
private Integer IPO;
private Integer questions;
private Integer answers;
private Party party;
private Date lastUpdate;
private char status;
private Collection<Portfolio> portfolios;
private Collection<AskOrder> askOrders;
private Collection<BidOrder> bidOrders;

 public Member() {

        this.lastUpdate = new Date();
    }

 public Member(String memberId,String forename, String surname, Integer position, 
         Integer majority, Integer IPO, Integer questions, Integer answers, Party party) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
        this.forename = forename;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.position = position;
        this.majority = majority;
        this.IPO = IPO;
        this.questions = questions;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.party = party;
        this.lastUpdate = new Date();
        this.askOrders = new ArrayList<AskOrder>();
        this.bidOrders = new ArrayList<BidOrder>();
        this.portfolios = new ArrayList<Portfolio>();
    }

    @Id
    public String getMemberId() {
        return memberId;
    }

    public void setMemberId(String memberId) {
        this.memberId = memberId;
    }

    public char getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(char status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }


    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public String getForename()
    {
        return forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename)
    {
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Integer getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Integer position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Integer getMajority() {
        return majority;
    }

    public void setMajority(Integer majority) {
        this.majority = majority;
    }

    public Integer getIPO() {
        return IPO;
    }

    public void setIPO(Integer iPO) {
        IPO = iPO;
    }

    public Integer getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(Integer questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public Integer getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(Integer answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Party getParty() {
        return party;
    }

    public void setParty(Party party) {
        this.party = party;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="member")
    public Collection<AskOrder> getAskOrders() 
    {
        return askOrders;
    }

    public void setAskOrders(Collection<AskOrder> orders)
    {
        this.askOrders = orders;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="member")
    public Collection<BidOrder> getBidOrders() 
    {
        return bidOrders;
    }

    public void setBidOrders(Collection<BidOrder> bidOrders)
    {
        this.bidOrders = bidOrders;
    }

    @ManyToMany //FIXME should probably be many to many - done
    public Collection<Portfolio> getPortfolios() {
        return portfolios;
    }

    public void setPortfolios(Collection<Portfolio> portfolios) {
        this.portfolios = portfolios;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a JOIN table, and you have no @Join annotation anywhere so won't have one as it stands. Read JPA documentation

Comment: Check out your "@ManyToOne //FIXME should probably be many to many" comment, as Member only has a single Portfolio and does not require a join table.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've added a jointable above but I'm not sure where to go from here as the data in the join table is still not persisted. When I create a portfolio how is the join table data created? Or do I have to do that explicitly?

Comment: Your mapping is wrong, but it's unclear what it should be. A portfolio has many members. But can one member belong to many portfolios, or just one?

Comment: If you are referring to Portfolio - Members relation then kindly EDIT your post and remove the other class and irrelevant fields, so then you can concentrate on what you say the question is about. Also if a relation is ManyToMany BIDIRECTIONAL then it needs __mappedBy__ specifying

Comment: I've removed the Trader class. A member can have many portfolios and a portfolio can have many members. I tried to set mappedBy="members" to Member.getPortfolios() but I got an error "In attribute 'portfolios', the "mapped by" attribute 'members' has an invalid mapping type for this relationship."

Comment: If you use mappedby in the member entity, then you have to declare the manytomany relation (jointable) in the portfolio entity.

Comment: "Passing the joint"-I want to work there. My job is just a bunch of squares that don't party.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Entity
    public class Portfolio
    {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private int id;

      @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable( name = "PortfolioMember",
        @JoinColumns : @JoinColumn( name = "Portfolio_ID", referencedColumnName="id" ),
        @InverseJoinColumns : @JoinColumn( name = "Member_ID", referencedColumnName="id" )
      )
      private List<Member> members;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Member
    {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private int id;

      @ManyToMany( mappedBy = members )
      private List<Portfolio> portfolios;
    }
```